# Swift - present/dismiss ViewController with UIImage animation

Tags: ios, swift, animation, uicollectionview, uiimageview

I would like to have an animation when pushing/dismissing my `ViewController`.

The best way to show you what I mean is to look at the N26: [Animation](https://streamable.com/o8aui)

In my case I have a `CollectionView` where the user can click on a `cell` to get to the next `ViewController` which I handle with a `tapCallback`:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    // if indexPath.item is less than data count, return a "Content" cell
    if indexPath.item < dataSourceArray.count {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "ContentCell", for: indexPath) as! ContentCell
        // set cell label
        cell.cellLabel.text = dataSourceArray[indexPath.item].name
        // set cell image
        cell.wishlistImage.image = dataSourceArray[indexPath.item].image
        if cell.wishlistImage.image == images[2] || cell.wishlistImage.image == images[3] {
            cell.priceLabel.textColor = .gray
            cell.priceEuroLabel.textColor = .gray
            cell.wishCounterLabel.textColor = .gray
            cell.wünscheLabel.textColor = .gray
        }
        // set background color
        cell.imageView.backgroundColor = dataSourceArray[indexPath.item].color
        cell.wishCounterView.backgroundColor = dataSourceArray[indexPath.item].color
        cell.priceView.backgroundColor = dataSourceArray[indexPath.item].color


        cell.customWishlistTapCallback = {

            // track selected index
            self.currentWishListIDX = indexPath.item

            let vc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "WishlistVC") as! WishlistViewController

            vc.wishList = self.dataSourceArray[self.currentWishListIDX]

            vc.theTableView.tableView.reloadData()
            self.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)

        }

        return cell
    }
```

To dismiss the `ViewController` the user simply has to tap a `button`:

```
@objc private func dismissView(){
    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

This is a screenshot of my `CollectionView` and the `ViewController` I present/dismiss:

[image]  [image]

Like I said I would like to have the exact same animation as in the video (also be able to "drag-dismiss" the `ViewController` but that is probably another question?).

If you anything is unclear feel free to ask.

I tried searching for that but I couldn't really find anything so I am grateful for any help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a really good library that does this functionality, it’s called [Hero](https://github.com/HeroTransitions/Hero).

If you want to make your own implementation you will need to use your own `UIViewControllerTransitioningDelegate`

Comment: Are you experienced with Hero? I am struggling right now. Could you maybe have a look at my latest question?